# Group rows based on akey + angular mat-table

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have to group rows based on the value in angular material table as follows:...

```
colA  colB  colC
abc   1     2
      2     3
xyz   1     2
```

My Json looks like below:

```
[
{
"colA":"abc",
"colB":1,
"colC": 2
},
{
"colA":"abc",
"colB":2,
"colC": 3
},
{
"colA":"xyz",
"colB":1,
"colC": 2
}
]
```

Right now with the current logic what i have written the table is displaying as follows:

```
colA  colB  colC
abc   1     2
abc   2     3
xyz   1     2
```

My Coding part is below:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table mat-elevation-z8" matSort #TableOneSort="matSort" multiTemplateDataRows>
//Here my column name logic goes here
</table>
```

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check with index if row - 1 has colA parameter === row. If yes don't display the title of it, if not display it. .

Something like:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
    <span ngIf="array[i].colA !== array[i - 1].colA">
         {{element.colA}}
    </span>
</td>
```

This might shift based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your time can you please give me some code sample.As i am new to angular i am not familiar with that. Where i have to put this logic in html??

Comment: it throws error colAof undefined. Whether its throwing error for 1st iteration??

Comment: Then put ngIf="array[i] && array[i].colA !== array[i - 1].colA"

Comment: Here the array what are referring is `[dataSource]="dataSource"` is datasource right??If i simply put `*ngIf="  dataSource[i].name "` itself throwing name of undefined

Comment: its not displaying the name itself\